# unit testing a recursive http request with angular httpbackend

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, httpbackend

I am doing unit testing on my AngularJS app using their setup with jasmine and karma. I have been using AngularJS mock `$httpbackend`:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend

The problem I have is testing the following module:

```
define([
    'angular',
    'app',
    'angularRoute',
    ], function (angular, app) {
        'use strict';

        app.config(function ( $httpProvider) {        
            /* Angular automatically adds this header to the request,
               preventing us from being able to make requests to the server on another port */
            delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
        }).factory('equipmentService', ['$http', '$rootScope', function($http, $rootScope) {
            var factory = {
                setEquipmentState: function(state){
                    this.equipmentState = state.state;
                    console.log('equipment state', this.equipmentState);
                    redirectState(this.equipmentState);
                }
            }
            var redirectState = function (state) {
                switch(state) {
                    case 'Active':
                        $location.path('/active');
                        break;
                    case 'Review':
                        $location.path('/review');
                        break;
                    default:
                        // don't change views
                }
            }

            function stateCheck () {
                $http.get($rootScope.backendServer+'/equipment/state/changed')
                .then(function (data) {
                    factory.setEquipmentState(data.data);
                })
                .then(stateCheck);
            }

            stateCheck();


            return factory;
        }]);
});
```

I always have a pending http request to the server; as soon as the server responds, send another http request. Because of this, even if my mock httpbackend is expecting the request, once it responds, I don't know how to avoid the error:

> Error: Unexpected request: GET url
>       No more request expected

Is there a way for me to ignore this error for this particular request? Or a way for the mock httpbackend to expect infinite requests to that url?

Answer (score 2):

One should use the  `$httpBackend.when` suite of methods when your tests are expecting more than one request to the same URL.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend

Answer (score 0):

You should use a combination of `$httpBackend.expect` and `$httpBackend.when` to cover a required call that can happen multiple times:

$httpBackend.expectPUT('URI')... (makes it required)
$httpBackend.whenPUT('URI')... (allows for multiple calls)